# Spring + Thymeleaf mail template - why are inline images attached to email?

Tags: spring, email, templates, thymeleaf

I'm using spring + thymeleaf to send emails. My mail template has few images which are displayed properly in the email, however i see that *unused* images are attached to the bottom of the email. I have business logic in the html, which decides what images to show and what not, so sometimes some images are not used but are attached. How do i get rid of them?

Any ideas?

Here is how i load the image in html:

```
<img src="cid:change-password" alt="">
```

Here is how i send the email:

```
 public void sendUsingTemplate(String fromEmail, String toEmail, String subject, String templateName, Map<String, Object> variables) {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setSubject(subject);

        final Context context = new Context(Locale.getDefault());
        variables.forEach((name, value) -> context.setVariable(name, value));

        String text = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
        helper.setText(text, true);
        helper.setFrom(fromEmail);
        helper.setTo(toEmail);

        Map<String, String> inlineResources = mailTemplateResourcesProvider.getInlineResources(templateName);
        inlineResources.forEach((contentId, file) -> addInlineWithoutCheckedException(helper, contentId, file));

        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error sending mail using template", e);
    }
```

Comment: external resources will never be loaded in an email, unless the user explicitly allows it to happen. it lets the external server know that the resource is being loaded, which is a privacy breach.

Comment: OK what about unused image?

Comment: If they're not being used, why attach them in the first place? it's not the mail client's job to decide "oh, this image isn't used in the html, I'll just silently delete that". Lots of images attached to emails never get referred to by the email's html, e.g. "Attached is a pic of the kids at camp".

Comment: because i render different stuff based on dynamic information. Sometimes i render image X, other times i don't.

Comment: then either keep track of what resources your renders require, and attach only the ones being used, or attach everything, and be resigned to sending out stuff that wasn't necessary.